# Ucp convergence and Emery Topology

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

maybe you can help me once again.

It is known that convergence in the semimartingale topology (Emery topology) implies ucp convergence. Can you think of an easy example, to show that the converse is not true?

Alternatively, one can also show that the space of semimartingales is not complete under ucp convergence.

Thank you very much!